# Is it sufficient that a class is POD to read it from binary?

Tags: c++, class

For a client/server application I need to send and recive c++ objects. I don't need the corresponding classes to do anything fancy but want to have maximal performance (regarding network traffic and computation). So I though of simply transferring them as binary strings. Basicly I want to be able to do the following

```
//Create original object
MyClass oldObj();

//save to char array
char* save = new char[sizeof(MyClass)];
memcpy(save, &oldObj, sizeof(MyClass));

//Somewhere of course there would be the transfer to the client/server

//Read back from char array
MyClass newObj();
memcpy(&newObj, save, sizeof(MyClass));
```

My question: What does my class need to fullfill in order for this to work? 
Naturaly Pointers as members won't work when transferring to another application. But is it sufficient that my Class is considered POD (in c++03 and/or c++11) and does not have any pointers or equivalents (like STL containers) as members?

Comment: Maybe you want to look into middleware frameworks which simplify this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both machines need to:

1. Have the same Endianess (for int)
2. The same floating point representation (double)
3. The same size for all types.
4. The Same compiler
5. The Same flags used to build the application.
6. Pointers dont transfer well.

**BUT** the network is going to be the slowest part here.
The cost of serializing most objects is going to be irrelevant compared to the cost of transfer. Of course the bigger your object the higher the cost but it takes a while before it is significant to make a dent.

The higher cost of maintenance is also you should factor in.

Comment: Does _the same compiler_ hold for a _standard-layout type_ where all the other conditions are satisfied?

Comment: I agree, compiler should be irrelevant if it's a POD?

Comment: I doubt it. As the compiler is allowed to add arbitrary padding for optimization.

Comment: Right, didn't think of that. Although you can always disable that, at least with gcc and msvc..

Comment: Just to be sure, _standard-layout_ types may have arbitrary padding? Even when satisfying 4 and 5?

Comment: Technically it does not need to be the same compiler. It just makes sure things are probably going to happen the same way. Underneath it is all about the layout the problem is that this compiler dependent.

Comment: @K-ballo: Not Arbitrary. Implementation defined. It can depend on the flags used as well. If you pass -O3 you may get a layout where all members are aligned to int boundaries for fast access. While -Os may give you a layout that is very packed to save space for size.

Comment: I know is a note and thus not normative, but what about _9/9_?

Comment: Is that a standard reference?

Comment: Yes, sorry, should really learn how to do the _S_ symbol... it reads _"[ Note: Standard-layout classes are useful for communicating with code written in other programming lan-guages. Their layout is specified in 9.2. —end note ]"_.

Comment: @K-ballo: Can't the linker decide to provide different values for the vptr of the same class (technically even the same linker across builds)? So you could end up with a deserialized object with a vptr that points to who knows where?

Comment: @Jon: A type with a virtual method wouldn't be _POD_

Comment: @K-ballo: Too much thinking makes one miss the obvious. Cheers!

Comment: From n3376: 9.2.13 `Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other;` To this me this just means implementation padding is allowed between members. This does not preclude 9.9 in your above comment as long as the compiler documents what it is doing thus allowing other languages to interface correctly.

Comment: +1 if only for "The cost of serializing most objects is going to be irrelevant compared to the cost of transfer." OP wants to maximize performance but clearly has not profiled; there's a reason why we take the time to compress data before we send it over the wire!

Answer (score 1):

> What does my class need to fulfill in order for this to work?

- It must not have pointer members, you already mention that.
- It must not have members whose size is implementation defined, like `int`.
- It must not have integers members, due to different endianness.
- It must not have floating point members, due to different representations.
- ...and probably more!

Basically, you cannot do that except for very particularly constrained scenarios. You will have to pick a protocol and make your data conform to it to send it through the network safely.

Is not a big deal since performance will be bounded by network speed and latency, not by the operations needed on your values to conform to the protocol.

Comment: "It must not have integers members, due to endianness." That is a little restrictive. The endian of the sender might match the endian of the receiver, or the class might be coded to swap the endian of those integers after `memcpy()` has been called.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That is outside the scope of the question, the OP asks about _simply transferring them as binary_. Otherwise, you are conforming to a protocol and none of my constrains hold anymore

Comment: Assuming that points 2..4 are "acceptable" - e.g. guaranteed running on identical hardware and use compilers with the same size definitions - would this then ensure binary compatibility or are there other layout factors (e.g. layout) to consider? (Rephrasing your comment in the other question, I think :D)

Comment: @pst: Assuming the compilation flags and library implementations are the same, then maybe... I wouldn't count on that though

Answer (score 1):

How much control do you have over the hardware/OS that this runs on? Are you writing code that is super-portable, or will it ONLY run on 32- and 64-bit x86 Windows [for example]?

To be fully "super-portable", as explained above, you can't have any form of "implementation defined" sized objects (such as int that can be 16, 18, 32, 36 or 64 bits, for example). Such items need to be stored as bytes of defined number and order to make sure it will not get cut off/re-ordered when transferring. Floating point can be even worse...

A lot of "super-portable" applications store their data as text. It's a little slower, but it makes it trivially portable, since text is just a stream of bytes whatever architecture you run it on, and it's ordered the same way whichever machine you use (as long as you stick to 0-9, A-Za-z, !?<>,.()*& and a few other characters - and beware of EBCDIC encoded machines, but they tend to handle "ascii-to-ebcdic" conversion). The other end just need to conver the text back to strings/integers/floats/doubles, whatever you need. A conversion from integer to string of digits takes one divide per digit (using hex or base-36 makes that a bit better, but makes it much less human readable - sometimes a good thing, sometimes a bad thing). This is clearly slower than storing 4 bytes. THe other drawback is that it's (depending on values used) often longer to store a number in text than as binary. So your network packets will be a little larger. This will have a greater impact than the conversion, as processors can do a lot of math in the time it takes to send 1KB with a 10Gbit network card. And of course, you need a few extra bytes (spaces, commas, newlines or whatever it may be) so that you can tell the difference between one number 123456 and three 12, 34, 56. [Of course, no need to use ", " between each]. And you need some code to parse the whole thing at the other end once it has arrived.

If you know that your system(s) always have 32-bit integers and IEEE-754 floating point numbers [these are extremely common!], then you may well get away with just worrying about byte order. And if you know that it's always going to be on "x86" or some such, you don't have to worry about byte order either. But you now may have to modify your code when you decide that "running my code on an iphone would be a good idea". Of course, you could leave that to the iphone side of things to conform to whatever the rest requires.

Answer (score -4):

Other answers have mentioned how it is possible to use a `class` for this purpose.  Personally, I prefer to use a `struct` instead.  In C++, a `struct` can have member methods/operators, constructor/destructor, supports inheritance, etc just like a `class` does.  However, a `struct` has a well-defined and predictable memory layout and can have that layout explicitally aligned via `#pragma` statements to add/remove the compiler's implicit padding (I have never tried aligning a `class` before, but I think it is supported).  I always use an 8bit-aligned `struct` for data that has to be exchanged outside of the app's process.  For all intents and purposes, in modern compilers, a `struct` is basically identical to a `class`, just the default visibility of its members is `public` instead of `private`.  But I like to keep `struct` and `class` separated for different purposes.  A `struct` is just a raw container of data that you can freely manpulate, overwrite in memory, etc.  A `class` is an object whose memory layout and padding is compiler-defined and should not be messed with.

Comment: Uh? `class` and `struct` are exactly the same thing, except for default access. Not _in modern compilers_ but in the _C++ standard_...

Comment: There is no difference between class and struct. They are identical apart from their default access specifiers.